# Complex Number $z_1 , z_2, z_3$ are represented by A,B,C respectively, which are in anticlockwise order. Find $|z_2-z_3|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> > ABC is triangle. Complex Number $z_1 , z_2, z_3$ are represented by A,B,C respectively, which are in anticlockwise order.
> > let $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|,$ and $\arg\bigg(\dfrac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}\bigg)=\dfrac{\pi}{6}$ .
> > Find $|z_2-z_3|$

**My Approach:**

Since $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|, $ so $z_1 , z_2, z_3$ must be lying on Circle of same radius and origin will be Circumcenter of triangle ABC. Since we are given angle at A is $\dfrac{\pi}{6}$ so angle at center will be $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$. Then I obtained $|z_2-z_3|=|z_2|=|z_3|=|z_1|$.

But given answer is in different form. How to get that form and other answer?
[image]

Comment: Would you like a solution to 13 and 14 as well?

Comment: @SrishDutta Yes, Please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Consider the above figure. This represents the given scenario.
Now, as you have mentioned, $$BC = OB = OC = OA$$
Let us consider $$\angle B = \alpha$$
Clearly, $$\angle AOC = 2 \alpha$$
Thus in $\Delta ABC$, by the cosine-rule,
$$AC^2 = OA^2 + OC^2 + 2OA \times OC cos2 \alpha$$
$$ \implies AC^2 = BC^2 + BC^2 + 2BC^2 cos2 \alpha$$
$$\implies AC^2 = 2BC^2(1 + cos2 \alpha)$$
$$\implies AC^2 = 4BC^2 cos^2 \alpha$$
$$\therefore BC = \frac{1}{2}AC cosec \alpha$$
Rewriting this we get,
$$|z_{2} - z_{3}| = \frac{1}{2}|z_{1} - z_{3}|  cosec(arg \frac{z_{1} - z_{2}}{z_{3} - z_{2}})$$
Hence, (B) is correct

Answer (score 2):

Now, to answer 13 and 14,

**13.**
We know,
$$Circumcentre (O) = (0,0)$$
Also, note that
$$Centroid (G) = \frac{z_{1} + z_{2} + z_{3}}{3}$$
Now, we know H, O and G lie on the same line (Euler's Line) and $HG:GO = 2:1$
Thus, by the section formula,
$$\frac{z_{H}}{3} = \frac{z_{1} + z_{2} + z_{3}}{3} \implies z_{H} = z_{1} + z_{2} + z_{3}$$

Hence, the answer is (C)

**14.**
Clearly in the parallelogram, $HC || BZ$.
Thus both the direction and magnitude of these 2 directed segments are equal. Hence,
$$z_{1} + z_{2} + z_{3} - z_{3} = z - z_{2} \implies z = z_{1} + 2z_{2}$$
Therefore,
$$z - z_{1} = 2z_{2} \implies |z| = 2|z_{2}| = 2|z_{2} - z_{3}|$$
Hence, (B) is correct.